# Using 2 view controllers in Swift as a way of producing a larger screen area

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS app which is just for debugging some other work I'm involved in. I've ran out of space on the first view controller (lots of buttons and images) and want to expand into a second view controller. I'm implemented a segue between the views and use the following code in the second viewcontroller to trigger functions in the first view controller:

```
@IBAction func imagePreset_1_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        firstViewController().functionX()
}
```

This works but if functionX has the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.source.text = "hello"
}
```

which is a label on firstViewController, then I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm new to Swift. Am I correctly creating a reference to the firstViewController or am I creating a new instance of it? It the problem that the label being updated is not in "scope"?

All I want is extra space for icons. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

**update**
So I've tried a scrolling view and this works but can anyone advise how to do what I'm trying to achieve with a second view controller accessing the functions in the first view controller? I think that's a nicer ux experience. Is it any easier using a tab bar?

Comment: If you use Xibs or Stoyboard `firstViewController()` is clearly not doing what you want. I'd say that you have IBOutlets (like `self.source`) and since you did `firstViewController()`, that is not calling the Xib/ViewControllerInStoryboard with it. So the IBOulets are nil.

Comment: Why don't you use only one view controller with a scroll view or table view to fit all the controls into?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I could implement a scroll view but i'd prefer not to. For the comment about my IBOutlets are nil, yes, this is what I think is happening. Is that because the way I am referencing firstViewController() is wrong? Is that creating a new view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a single ViewController with scrollable view inside ?

Using this, you'll be able to display as many content as you'd like :)